# Adapt PyQt4 code to PyQt5, problem with SIGNAL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4, qt-signals

I am converting a code from PyQt4 to PyQt5
I encounter two difficulties, first that a signal dictionary is created with the name of the signal and the signal

```
MY_SIGNALS = {
     'clicked': SIGNAL ('clicked'),
     'currentIndexChanged': SIGNAL ('currentIndexChanged')
     ...
     }
```

Second, in a function I receive a widget and a signal name in such a way that

```
def connect_actions (received_action, my_control):
     ...
     connect (my_control, MY_SIGNALS [received_action], function_exec)
```

One solution is to check the received string and the widget

```
if my_control is QtWidgets.QPushButton:
    if received_action is "clicked":
         my_pushbutton.clicked.connect (function_exec)
```

but there are dozens of widgets and tokens, is there a way to adapt the code in such a
way to assign a token by name like in PyQt4?

How can I adapt this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def connect_actions(received_action, my_control):
     getattr(my_control, received_action).connect(function_exec)
```